# How to share parameters between multiple tasks in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Suppose I want to pass a long list of arguments to multiple tasks - is there an easy way to define them once and then share them in all tasks?

```
tasks:                                 
   - name: test1                         
     test1:                       
       param1=value1
       ...
       param99=value99
     ...
   - name: test10                         
     test10:                       
       param1=value1
       ...
       param99=value99
```

Answer (score 2):

In a playbook, you can add a `vars` section.

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    param1: value1
    param99: value99
  tasks:
     - name: hello world
  roles:
     - some_role
```

Comment: I am actually developing some new modules and I don't think there is a way to access the variables from the module code (without having to pass them as parameters).

Comment: you should reword your question. Ansible modules avoid using implicit parameters, likely because side effects are a code smell. However, you can pass a data structure to each module.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [`module_defaults`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html):

```yaml
vars:
  common_parameters:
    param1: value1
    ...
    param99: value99
module_defaults:
  test1: "{{ common_parameters }}"
  test10: "{{ common_parameters }}"
tasks:                                 
- name: test1                         
  test1:                       
    ...
- name: test10                         
  test10:                       
    ...
```

If all modules are from a common collection, then consider to ask the deverloper of that collection to add a [module defaults group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html#module-defaults-groups) to their `meta/runtime.yml`:

```yaml
# meta/runtime.yml
action_groups:
  test1and10:
  - test1
  - test10
```

and then in your playbook

```yaml
module_defaults:
  group/namespace.collection.test1and10:
    param1: value1
    ...
    param99: value99
```

Comment: Thanks to the matrix channel `#users:ansible.com` for the appropriate hints!